# Are the owner benefits from Impersonate Tax Collector part of an action?

Tags: lords-of-waterdeep

The Lords of Waterdeep expansion card Impersonate Tax Collector lets you take the main benefit and the owner benefit on your buildings. Are both of these rewards part of the action of assigning an agent to that space, or is the owner benefit separate? If it is part of the same action, it should trigger other plot quests, such as Bribe the Shipwrights.

**If a player has completed Impersonate Tax Collector and Bribe the Shipwrights, and controls The Three Pearls, when they assign an agent to this building do they get the extra rogue from Bribe the Shipwrights?**

Impersonate Tax Collector says

> Whenever you assign an agent to a
>   Building you control, you also gain the owner benefit.

Bribe the Shipwrights says

> "Whenever you take an action that provides any
>   coins, also take 1 Rogue from the supply and place it in your tavern."

The Three Pearls has an owner benefit of two coins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [FAQ for Lords of Waterdeep](https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Lords_of_Waterdeep_FAQ), there is a question which seems to answer this question:

> Q: If a plot quest gives me resources for having taken an action, did I gain those resources as a part of taking the action?
>
> A: No. You gained the extra resources from the effect of the plot quest, not from the action itself.
>
> Note 2: The benefits of plot quests, and the rewards for completing a quest, never count as being a part of an action.

Since your plot card(s) are what are giving you the benefit of the Owner's action, this would seem to indicate that you do not receive the extra resource.

Comment: That's certainly one way of looking at it, but the situation is more complicated. Impersonate Tax Collector doesn't ever mention giving you resources.. It changes the way that the "owner benefit" rule works. If you visit Three Pearls, you get gold from the (modified) rules of the game, not the text of Impersonate Tax Collector. Contrast with Bribe the Shipwrights, which just gives you a rogue.

Comment: I don't think so.  Impersonate Tax Collector is a plot quest, correct?

Then, when you get the owner benefit, according to the rules, it is not your action giving you that benefit, but the plot quest.  Thus, for Bribe the Shipwrights, when you get the owner benefit, you are not taking an action for it.

Comment: Put, perhaps, a bit more succinctly:  The Plot Quest reward (getting the owner's benefit) breaks the line of the results of your action.  Anything after that is the result of the plot quest, not the action.